# How do I make a text file appear to type itself using a batch file?

Tags: file, batch-file, text

What I'm trying to achieve is for my Batch file to open Notepad and start typing automatically. Here's my code so far:

```
@echo off
Start notepad
```

but where do I go from here? I've tried:

```
@echo off
Start notepad
type "stuff" 
exit
```

and similar things but it didn't work.

Is there a way to do that in Batch?

Comment: you're not going to accomplish this with a .bat file. That's WAY beyond what they're intended to do

Comment: You should look into vbscript and using the sendkeys function

Answer (score 5):

Here's a little toy I whipped up to type out the text that's in the lineN variables, in a quasi-human style, to the console screen.

See the code for a tip on how to speed it up or slow it down.

```
@echo off
:: Ghost typer
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set lines=6


set "line1=Twinkle twinkle little star"
set "line2=How I wonder what you are"
set "line3=Up above the world so high"
set "line4=Like a diamond in the sky"
set "line5=Twinkle twinkle little star"
set "line6=How I wonder what you are"


for /f %%a in ('"prompt $H&for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%a"

for /L %%a in (1,1,%lines%) do set num=0&set "line=!line%%a!"&call :type

pause>nul
goto :EOF

:type
set "letter=!line:~%num%,1!"
set "delay=%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%"
set "delay=%delay:~-6%"
if not "%letter%"=="" set /p "=a%bs%%letter%" <nul

:: adjust the 3 in the line below: higher is faster typing speed

for /L %%b in (1,3,%delay%) do rem
if "%letter%"=="" echo.&goto :EOF
set /a num+=1
goto :type
```

Comment: It works like a charm! :) But would it be possible to explain what `for /f %%a in ('"prompt $H&for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%a"`? Without it an extra character is always printed after each `letter` so the backspace you set as prompt with `prompt $H` is used somehow but I can't figure out how and what that `for /f` loop, the `for`-loop and the `BS` variable are for.

Comment: @J.Baoby Late comment for foxidrive (R.I.P) That line generates a backspace in `BS` since `set /p` will drop single space prompts an additional char is print first then `BS` and the intended char.

Answer (score 0):

This would be -- umm I don't know if even possible in Batch.
**BUT**, you could do this in one file if you code it in VBScript.

```
set ghost = wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

ghost.run "notepad"
wscript.sleep 3000
ghost.sendkeys "Hello."
wscript.sleep 1000
ghost.sendkeys "I am a magical ghost "
wscript.sleep 1000
ghost.sendkeys "who possesed your keyboard."
```

You save this as `.vbs` instead of `.bat`!

```
Explanation:

set ghost = wsc .... bla bla bla
```

- Creates a new WSCRIPTShell object (which is required for opening notepad AND "posessing" your keyboard"

```
ghost.run "notepad"
```

- Opens notepad.

```
wscript.sleep 3000
```

- "Sleeps" for 3000 milliseconds (That's 3 seconds)

```
ghost.sendkeys "Hello."
```

- Types "Hello." (Without quotes of course.)

It should be easy to adapt this to your needs.
EDIT: "Sleeping" aka pausing is ALWAYS in milliseconds. You get milliseconds by multiplying seconds by 1000. E.g. 1 Second = 1000 Milliseconds Because **1 * 1000 = 1000**

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
echo Hello what is you name?
set /p %name%= 
echo>Hello%name%.txt I have just taken over you computer.
:: the set command works in this format
:: The above echo will not show up in a command prompt if echo is off 
:: You must use "echo >" for the batch file to create a text file
:: The word that you put immediately after the ">" will be the name of the file
:: you can also use a "%-%" command for the file name.
:: The batch file will create a new text file for each "echo >" command used
:: So if you want a lot of text in one document write all of the text on one line
:: P.S. I found this by accident while creating an inventory program XD
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set wshShell = wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
do
wscript.sleep 100
wshshell.sendkeys "{}"
loop
```

If you type in a Key on the keyboard in CAPS in between the {} you can make it continuously type that letter!

BTW save this as as .vbs file instead of a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Lookup the "pv" command and check the option "-L"

"
Data Transfer Modifiers

-L RATE, --rate-limit RATE
Limit the transfer to a maximum of RATE bytes per second. A suffix of "k", "m", "g", or "t" can be added to denote kilobytes (*1024), megabytes, and so on.
"

SO...

> echo "twinkle twinkle little star
>
> > how I wonder what you are" | **pv -qL 10**

http://www.ivarch.com/programs/yum.shtml