# How can I make batch type slowly, letter by letter?

Tags: batch-file

I was wondering if there was a way to slow the rate at which the prompt writes, especially when using the `type` command. If only line by line. If `type`ing a file ran code inside too, I could use that, but I can't find a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here for a method to type some text slowly, and in this case it shows in a style that is like someone typing the text.

[How do I make a text file appear to type itself using a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667457/how-do-i-make-a-text-file-appear-to-type-itself-using-a-batch-file/21672365#21672365)

Comment: Thanks! I saw this link before as well... I guess I just didn't read it well enough and assumed it was something done with extra mods/whatever the term is.

Answer (score 1):

Timing would be a problem for delays of < 1 second and would need an external helper resource.

Line by line per second (Win 7/8);

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (the.file) do (
  @echo %%a
  timeout 1 > NUL
)
```

(You could use a counter to batch the delays per n-lines)

Comment: See the link in my answer - it can be done quite effectively without external helper files.

Answer (score 1):

Hey i know this might be late but I figured out a really easy way to do this :3 (maybe just for me cause im a noob)

Any ways lets get started.

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set string=Hello World

for /L %%a in (1, 1, 11) do (
set sting=!string:~0,%%a! 
echo ^>!sting!
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
if %%a GEQ 11 goto eof
cls 
)

:eof
pause >nul
```

so yeah that is one way to do this, there are like other way but this for me is the easiest to understand :3

ps. this is just a structure, you can do many things with this, you can make it write out like a whole document, build on the structure and improve it hehe. Get building!

I goto my ideas from this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2C3szhwuvL0&index=58&list=PL69BE3BF7D0BB69C4

Answer (score -1):

**maybe you can change the time from letter to letter by using**

```
@echo off
color 0a
echo h
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
cls
echo he
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
cls
echo hel
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
cls
echo hell
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
cls
echo hello
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
cls
pause
```

i dont know the times but you can get a try if its works