# Having some trouble with a fun batch file

Tags: batch-file, text, typing

So i'm just a casual joe who discovered you can do some fun stuff with batch. Anyways i'm trying to make a cool hidden folder type deal on a usb for a friend.

Only problem is I really want it to type out the questions like its a real AI or person asking. I found a solution to realistic typing here. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667457/how-do-i-make-a-text-file-appear-to-type-itself-using-a-batch-file)

This was solution example

```html
@echo off
:: Ghost typer
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set lines=6


set "line1=Twinkle twinkle little star"
set "line2=How I wonder what you are"
set "line3=Up above the world so high"
set "line4=Like a diamond in the sky"
set "line5=Twinkle twinkle little star"
set "line6=How I wonder what you are"


for /f %%a in ('"prompt $H&for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%a"

for /L %%a in (1,1,%lines%) do set num=0&set "line=!line%%a!"&call :type

pause>nul
goto :EOF

:type
set "letter=!line:~%num%,1!"
set "delay=%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%"
set "delay=%delay:~-6%"
if not "%letter%"=="" set /p "=a%bs%%letter%" <nul

:: adjust the 3 in the line below: higher is faster typing speed

for /L %%b in (1,3,%delay%) do rem
if "%letter%"=="" echo.&goto :EOF
set /a num+=1
goto :type
```

So I just took that replaced the line with my own.. "Enter password.." made sure to set it to one line.

But then thats where I hit the problem. It seems to be a loop or something. Anytime I try to get it to goto a new set of commands it breaks the whole thing. where am I able to like add a goto in this to start a new bit of commands?

Comment: Where's your code? Paste it into your question body so we can help.

Comment: K I added the bit of code I was trying to manipulate to the post sorry.

Comment: that code runs fine. Where is the part, you have problems with?

Comment: The problem im having is I dont know how to add to like do more to the batch then that.. Whenever I try to add another line of commands it ignores them because its like looping to check parameters that make it animated. 

I dont know where to inset the next like goto so I can keep it going you know? 

I like want it to ask for the password but then I want to add variables and other such stuff... then down the line have it type stuff out again.

Comment: @Dubby has my answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I fully understand the problem you're describing in your post and your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42199490/having-some-trouble-with-a-fun-batch-file#comment71562577_42199490), it looks like you don't fully understand your code. I'll (try to) explain a bit why some places in your script will never be reached by the cmd interpreter. With the result that code on these places will never be executed.

Let's consider the first part of your code (where the cmd interpreter begins):

```
@echo off
:: Ghost typer
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set lines=6


set "line1=Twinkle twinkle little star"
set "line2=How I wonder what you are"
set "line3=Up above the world so high"
set "line4=Like a diamond in the sky"
set "line5=Twinkle twinkle little star"
set "line6=How I wonder what you are"


for /f %%a in ('"prompt $H&for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%a"

for /L %%a in (1,1,%lines%) do set num=0&set "line=!line%%a!"&call :type

pause>nul
goto :EOF
```

You disable the printing of each command with [`@echo off`](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html), enable [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), set all your variables containing each a line of your text, use a `for /f` loop to get a backspace character that will be used during the typing of the text (I don't quite get why the [`prompt`](https://ss64.com/nt/prompt.html) command is used with for-loop and double quotes though) and use a [`for /L`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html) loop to iterate over all your `lines` and type them out with a [call](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) to the `:type` function implemented in the second part of your script. After that `pause>nul` will cause the console to wait until the user presses on a key. And finally **`goto :EOF` is used to terminate the execution of the current batch-script** (or "context", see further) else the cmd-interpreter would go on and execute the code under the `:type` subroutine an extra time (which is most probably not your intention). As explained in [Microsoft's documentation for the `goto` command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755012.aspx), `:EOF` is a predefined label that can be used to exit the current batch-script. So **whatever you put under the `goto :EOF` will never get executed** or at least not in the same "context" (see further to understand what is meant with "same context").

But then, how comes the `:type` subroutine gets executed and the `goto :EOF` there doesn't exit your batch-script?

```
:type
set "letter=!line:~%num%,1!"
set "delay=%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%"
set "delay=%delay:~-6%"
if not "%letter%"=="" set /p "=a%bs%%letter%" <nul

:: adjust the 3 in the line below: higher is faster typing speed

for /L %%b in (1,3,%delay%) do rem
if "%letter%"=="" echo.&goto :EOF
set /a num+=1
goto :type
```

That's thanks to the [`call`](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) command. `:type` is just a label like others but the reason why I call it subroutine is because you use `call` and not [`goto`](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html) to execute what's under it. A [`goto`](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html) will just jump to the label you gave it and forget about what it was doing before the `goto`. The `call` command on the other hand, will create a new context on top of the context in which the script is being executed. This way, one can go back to where the execution of the script stopped before the `call` when the new context is closed and exited (a little bit like calling and returning from a subroutine). To exit that context the cmd parser needs to encounter a normal end of (script) file, an explicit [`exit`](https://ss64.com/nt/exit.html) command or, as in this case, a `goto :EOF`. BUT even in the context of the `:type` subroutine, code below the `goto :type` will not be executed. Indeed, after the `for /L` under the  `:type` label there are 2 cases:

1. either `%letter%` is empty: in this case an empty line will be printed (`echo.`) and the context will be closed because of the `goto :EOF`. Which means it goes back to the context of the script (where it will continue with the `for /L` iterating over your text)
2. or `%letter%` is not empty: variable `num` is then incremented and the cmd interpreter jumps back to the `:type` label (because of the `goto :type`) without ever reaching code under `goto :type` (get the difference between `goto` and `call`? in case of a `call` it would've executed the code under it at a certain moment).

Now I can show you the places where you can add code that has to be executed and the places where code won't get executed at all **except** if you place a label in those places and use a `goto` or a `call` (beware of the differences and dangers ) to that label in the areas where you can add code. I have also modified the `for /L` and the `if` where you were using [`&`](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/condexec.php). [`&`](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/condexec.php)s make your code a bit more unreadable. In your case they weren't really needed so I've put each command on its own line and enclosed the commands with `(...)`.

```
@echo off
:: Ghost typer
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set lines=6


set "line1=Twinkle twinkle little star"
set "line2=How I wonder what you are"
set "line3=Up above the world so high"
set "line4=Like a diamond in the sky"
set "line5=Twinkle twinkle little star"
set "line6=How I wonder what you are"


for /f %%a in ('"prompt $H&for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%a"

REM Here is place OK 1
REM Gets executed before the text prints

for /L %%a in (1,1,%lines%) do (
    set num=0
    set "line=!line%%a!"
    call :type
)

REM Here is place OK 2
REM Gets executed after the text prints

pause>nul
goto :EOF

! THIS PART IS NEVER REACHED BY THE CMD-INTERPRETER !

:type
set "letter=!line:~%num%,1!"
set "delay=%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%"
set "delay=%delay:~-6%"
if not "%letter%"=="" set /p "=a%bs%%letter%" <nul

:: adjust the 3 in the line below: higher is faster typing speed

for /L %%b in (1,3,%delay%) do rem
if "%letter%"=="" (
    echo.
    REM Place OK 3
    REM Here can come code that gets executed after each line is printed
    goto :EOF
)
set /a num+=1
goto :type

! THIS PLACE WILL NEVER BE REACHED BY THE CMD-INTERPRETER EITHER !
```

I hope this long post helped. Don't hesitate to ask questions if you have any.

Good luck!