# Display a sentence letter by letter

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I try to create a batch script that displays a sentence letter by letter. But do not know how. Have a script but it displays only word by word and ignores spaces.

Another question is if it is posslible to make a letter appear after a period that is less than 1000 ms?

My bad code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "string_list=Hello world"
for %%s in (%string_list%) do (
  set "var=!var!%%~s"
  timeout /t 1 >nul
  cls
  echo !var!
)
echo.
echo.
echo.
timeout /t 1 >nul
```

Comment: There is a nice implementation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667457/how-do-i-make-a-text-file-appear-to-type-itself-using-a-batch-file/21672365#21672365), by a sadly missed member of many batch related forums, foxidrive.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar idea to the answer I provided in my comment, it uses a one second delay between each letter printed.

```bat
@Echo Off

Set "STRING=I am a string of text"

For /F %%A In ('"Prompt $H&For %%B In (1) Do Rem"') Do Set "BS=%%A"

For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('CMD/U/CEcho^=%STRING%^|Find /V ""'
) Do Set/P "=a%BS%%%A"<Nul & Timeout 1 1>Nul

Pause
```

If you find, that the one second between letters is too long, you'll need to use a different command in place of `Timeout 1` to shorten it. For example `PathPing 127.0.0.1 -n -q 1 -p 225` just adjust the final number as necessary.