# self-writing text - animation in batch

Tags: batch-file, animation, text

I want to create animation of self-writing text. I tried using cls and timeouts, like this:

```
echo s
CSCRIPT SLEEP.VBS 100> nul
cls
echo so
CSCRIPT SLEEP.VBS 100> nul
cls 
echo som
```

It would solve my problem, but it would be very big amount of code and time to write it. I did some research, but I couldnt find this in **batch**.

Comment: Perhaps a [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subroutine) could help?

Comment: If you're scripting for windows 10, consider also the use of [virtual terminal sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) in either a function or macro.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a text file appear to type itself using a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667457/how-do-i-make-a-text-file-appear-to-type-itself-using-a-batch-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
:slowtype string delay
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
cls
set "string=%~1"
set /a delay=%~2 %= if the number is invalid delay will be 0 =%
set "slp=typeperf "\System\Processor Queue Length" -si %delay% -sc 1 >nul"
call :strlen string len


for /l %%L in (0;1;%len%) do (
    %slp%
    break|set/p=!string:~%%L,1!
    
)


exit /b 0

:strlen  StrVar  [RtnVar]
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  set "s=#!%~1!"
  set "len=0"
  for %%N in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
    if "!s:~%%N,1!" neq "" (
      set /a "len+=%%N"
      set "s=!s:~%%N!"
    )
  )
  endlocal&if "%~2" neq "" (set %~2=%len%) else echo %len%
exit /b
```

example usage:

```
call slowType.bat "test message" 2
```

You can try also with embedded in the batch jscript code(should not have issues with special characters).Mind that this time the delay is in milliseconds:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment
    @echo off
    cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~nx0" %*
    exit /b %errorlevel%
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end JScript comment */

var string = WScript.Arguments.Item(0);
var delay = parseInt(WScript.Arguments.Item(1));

for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    WScript.Sleep(delay);
    WScript.StdOut.Write(string.charAt(i));
}
```

usage:

```
call slowTypeJS.bat "test message" 100
```

[**here's a version**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/slowTypeJS.bat) of the script with some checks and validations.

Comment: well, it works, thanks, but whitespace between "test" and "message" is missing.

Answer (score 2):

Further to my comment on your question regarding virtual terminal codes with Windows 10:

Virtual terminal codes can be used to reposition the cursor, erase text from a given position, Set the graphics mode of text (color), among a number of other features, details of which can be found at the link provided in the code.

Here is an example of how a macro function can be built to simulate a typing / erase typing effect. A delay between the display of each character is effected by calling a nonexistent label and redirecting the stderr output to nul.

Substring modification is used at the expansion of the macro to Declare an integer for the number of times the delay is to be enacted. See `Set /?` for information on Substring Modification.

```bat
@echo off & Cls
(Set \n=^^^

%= Newline Variable for macro definitions. Do NOT modify this or above two lines. =%)
rem /* Used to test if substitution is used when macro is expanded */
 Set "Hash=#"
rem /* Define Escape Control Character for Virtual Terminal code usage */
 For /F %%a in ('Echo Prompt $E ^|cmd')Do Set "\E=%%a"
::: VT reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences

rem /* Usage: %Write:#=Integer%{output string}{StringlengthVarname}{OPTIONAL-VT code for output Color} */
rem /* Switch: /s = Hide cursor */
 Set Write=For %%n in ( 1 2 ) Do if %%n==2 ( %\n%
  If not "!Args:/s=!" == "!Args!" ( ^<nul Set /P "=%\E%[?25l" ) Else ( ^<nul Set /P "=%\E%[?25h" ) %\n%
  For /F "Tokens=1,2,3 delims={}" %%1 in ("!Args!") Do if not "%%~1" == "" ( %\n%
   If "#" == "!Hash!" ( Set "Delay=0" ) else ( Set "Delay=#" ) %\n%
   Set "out.string=%%~1" %\n%
   Set /A "%%~2.lines=0,eol=0,.Delay=0" %\n%
   If not "%%~3" == "" ( Set "out.color=%%~3" ) Else ( Set "out.color=0;37" ) %\n%
   Echo/!out.color!^|Findstr.exe /RX "[0123456789;]*" ^> nul ^|^| ( Set "out.color=0;7" ) %\n%
   For /F "Tokens=1,2 Delims==" %%G in ( 'Set "%%~2.Length[" 2^^^> nul ' ) Do ( Set "%%G=0" )%\n%
   For /L %%i in ( 0 1 800 ) Do if not "!out.string:~%%i,1!" == "" ( %\n%
   If !Delay! NEQ 0 ( set /A ".Delay=!random! %%(!Delay!*2)" 2^> nul ) %\n%
    if "!out.string:~%%i,2!" == "\n" ( %\n%
     Set /A "%%~2.LENGTH[!%%~2.LINES!]+=1,%%~2.LINES+=1,EOL=1" %\n%
     Echo/%\n%
    ) Else ( %\n%
     If !eol! EQU 0 ( %\n%
      ^<nul Set /P "=%\E%[0m%\E%[!out.color!m!out.string:~%%i,1!%\E%[0m" %\n%
      Set /A "%%~2.length[!%%~2.lines!]+=1" %\n%
     )  Else ( Set /A "eol-=1" ) %\n%
     For /L %%f in ( 1 1 !.Delay! ) Do Call :Delay 2^> nul %\n%
    ) %\n%
 )))Else Set Args=

rem /* Usage: %Clear:#=Integer%{StringlengthVarname} */
rem /* Alternate Usage: %Clear:#=Integer%{Integer-Lines-to-remove}{Integer-Characters-to-remove}{Integer-Offset-remove-from} */
 Set Clear=For %%n in ( 1 2 ) Do if %%n==2 ( %\n%
  If not "!Args:/s=!" == "!Args!" ( ^<nul Set /P "=%\E%[?25l" )Else ( ^<nul Set /P "=%\E%[?25h" ) %\n%
  If "#" == "!Hash!" ( Set "Delay=0" ) else ( Set "Delay=#" ) %\n%
  For /F "Tokens=1,2,3 delims={}" %%1 in ( "!Args!" )Do ( %\n%
   If not "%%~3" == "" ( Set "erase.stop=%%~3" ) Else ( Set "erase.stop=0" ) %\n%
   If not "!%%~1.lines!" == "" ( Set "Del.lines=!%%~1.lines!" )Else ( Set "Del.lines=%%~1" ) %\n%
   For /L %%l in ( !Del.lines! -1 0 ) Do ( %\n%
    If not "!%%~1.length[%%l]!" == "" ( Set "Str.len=!%%~1.length[%%l]!" ) Else ( Set "Str.len=%%~2" ) %\n%
    ^<nul Set /P "=%\E%[!Str.len!G" %\n%
    For /L %%i in ( !erase.stop! 1 !Str.len! ) Do ( %\n%
     If !Delay! GTR 0 ( set /A ".Delay=!random! %%!Delay! + !Delay!" 2^> nul )Else ( Set ".Delay=0" ) %\n%
     ^<nul Set /P "=%\E%D%\E%[0m %\E%D" %\n%
     For /L %%f in ( 1 1 !.Delay! )Do Call :Delay 2^> nul %\n%
    ) %\n%
    If not "%%l" == "0" ^<nul Set /P "=%\E%[1F" %\n%
   ) %\n%
 ))Else Set Args=
 
 Setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
rem /*usage Examples*/
 %Write:#=15%{"Types letter by letter\n"}{str1}{48;2;220;140;0} /s
 %Write:#=10%{"Force a newline using backslashn\n"}{str2}{48;2;200;0;0} /s
 %Write:#=5%{"Doubleqoute to guard against Poison Characters: & | < > * ~ ( )\nExclamation marks '^^^!' and Carets '^^^^' require triple escaping\n"}{str3}
 %Write%{""Instantly" output text by expanding %%write%% macro without substring modification\n"}{str4}{48;2;150;150;200}
 %Write%{"Supress the cursor using the /s switch.\n"}{str5}{48;2;225;80;80}
 %Write%{"Notes:\n - Curly Braces used as input delim characters and cannot be included in string.\n - Virtual terminal codes tested for valid characters:\n   - Incorrect characters in the Arg for VT codes will output colour as black on white.\n   - Invalid sequences such as 7;;31 are not tested for.\n"}{str6}{invalidVTarg}
 Timeout /T 1 /nobreak > nul
 Pause > nul
 For %%i in (6 5)Do %Clear%{str%%i}
 %Clear:#=8%{str4} /s
 %Clear:#=4%{str3}
 %Clear:#=2%{str2}
 %Clear:#=1%{str1} /s
 %Write:#=10%{"Example Complete\n"}{str1}{38;2;0;160;180}
 Timeout /T 1 /nobreak > nul
 Pause > nul
 %Clear:#=20%{str1}{8}{10}
 %Write:#=7%{"now complete.\n"}{str1}{48;2;0;180;140}
 Goto :Eof
```